# How to sync useState of parent component

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

**I'm getting this error**
*Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.*

**In parent component:**

```
const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    percentageOfCost: 100,
    howMuchExpectedMoney: 0,
    state: USStates[0],
    stateName: USStates[0].label,
    schoolType: USStates[0]['In-State Public University'],
    educationType: 'In-State Public University',
    expectedMoneyFromOtherSrc:
      filteredChildren[0].isContributionNotByImmediateMember === 'true'
        ? 'yes'
        : 'no',
  });  
return(  
   <child formState={formState} setFormState={setFormState}/>  
);
```

**In child component**

```
setFormState(() => ({
      ...formState,
      stateName: currStateName,
      educationType: currEducationType,
      state: currState[0],
      schoolType: currState[0][currEducationType],
    }));
```

How Can I use useEffect for this scenario? So my useState is synchronous.

Comment: This error happens when your component is no longer mounted and you are trying to set the state. It can happen for a number of different reasons but the most common is that you have some kind of conditional render or you are pushing to a different page with router and then there is some kind of setState happening on that unmounted component. But it is impossible to tell from the code you posted. How is your component being unmounted?

Comment: @SteveK Actually I'm pushing it to a different page and using setState on that page. So what should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: What do you mean when you say pushing to a new page and setting the state on that page? Because from the error you are trying to set the state on a component that no longer exists. Can you edit the post with the relevant code so we can better help you?

Comment: @SteveK but I'm passing that useState variable(formState) to its child. So,why Im getting the error still?

Comment: Like I said before it is not that you are setting the state. It is that you are setting the state on a component that no longer exists. We would need the relevant code to determine what is happening. Is your setFromState function in some kind of submit function for your form that is pushing to a new page? Until I can see why your component is no longer available when the state is being set there is no way for me to tell what is happeing. Just posting code of the setState function doesn't really show anything.